# Separated php process stop all site

Tags: php

I'm wanting to run a separated php process, in my server, processes operate separately, but when this test is running, all the rest of the site is not working, ie, the entire site is waiting for him to finish.

When I use:

```
    ignore_user_abort( true );
    set_time_limit(0);

    while( true )
    {
        sleep( 10 );
    }
```

The above code works perfectly, but when I include the registry, controllers and database drivers, the rest of the site stay waiting

E.g:

```
    ignore_user_abort( true );
    set_time_limit(0);

    //Registry, controllers, DB, etc.

    while( true )
    {
        //code[...]
        sleep( 10 );
    }
```

Comment: That's because the script never returns. What is the script doing?

Comment: I think it important that you try to figure out what in `//code[...]` makes other pages 'hang'. A game of trial and error. If you know what command makes php 'hang', then users here might be able to tell you how to resolve it.

Comment: Any sessions in use? If so, note that sessions use locking. You can avoid it by calling `session_write_close()` ASAP and then only read from the session variables.

Comment: You shouldn't run a thing like this in a webserver, _however_, if you _must_, call `session_write_close()` in the long running thing, so it will not block other requests using the same session id.

Comment: @tlenss Yes, but I don't think it should hang *other* pages. He also claims the first piece of code 'works perfectly', meaning that something in the infinite running code in the second part is blocking other php processes from running (or hangs similar parts of the code in other php processes).

Comment: @Sumurai8 - It's not about //code [...] I have tested only the while with no code inside.

Comment: does a .txt page hang? if so, its a webserver issue.

Comment: @[.you++] Thank you all for the answers and comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use sessions, you should read up on php's session locking model, in particular see `session_write_close()`.

There may also be webserver limitations here, where theres only so many worker processes or threads available. There's many webservers and many ways to install php, but, regardless, if you exaust the worker pool, you will hang the webserver if you do stuff like sleep() or anything else that takes a long time.

In general, you should keep long running scripts out of your webserver, completely. Write a separate background process to do this stuff.

Comment: Okay, the problem was the lack of session_write_close();